# Charset UTF-8 for external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, character-encoding

I add an external JavaScript file like this:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="js/panel.js" ></script>
</head>
```

But the text stored in **panel.js** file is displayed like this in the HTML file:

```
H69�*
```

When I put JavaScript code in the HTML page, the text is displayed properly. But when I put JavaScript code in **panel.js**, it does not work.

Comment: Is `panel.js` definitely saved as UTF-8?

Comment: i use centos and do not know how to save file as utf-8

Comment: lying about the encoding on the script tag won't help, you need to adjust the server or use ascii js files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then the file maybe is not properly saved as UTF-8.

```
$ file -i panel.js
```

What's the output?

If you use, for example Vi, open the file and save it with:

```
:w ++enc=utf-8 %
```

Answer (score 0):

in the mac OS it is a capital -i...like this:

```
file -I
```